# I have selected an html theme on theme forest which is fulfilling all my business needs. Which CMS should i go with?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, content-management-system

I have heard that drupal is not user friendly and hard to adjust with. Is it safe to use these cms?

Comment: This forum is not for that kind of topics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes both WordPress & Drupal are safe to use as CMS. Yes WordPress might be more user friendly. You will need to get your html theme converted into WordPress theme to use WordPress as CMS for your website.